cannot read configuration from app.config
I am trying to read configuration parameter from app.config file that looks like following:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="key" value="test" />
  </appSettings>  
</configuration>

Here is the code that tries to retrieve "key":
var value = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key"];
Console.WriteLine($"value={value}");

The output of the code snippet is:
value=

Due to I am running on Ubuntu I have created both app.config and App.config and put it into 3 locations:

project root
production code root
tests root

Here is the full list of my config files including those that have been created by build.
./app.config
./CompanyNETSDK/app.config
./CompanyNETSDK/bin/Debug/net6.0/CompanyDotNetSdk.dll.config
./CompanyNETSDK/App.config
./App.config
./CompanyDotNetSdk.Tests/app.config
./CompanyDotNetSdk.Tests/bin/Debug/net6.0/CompanyDotNetSdk.dll.config
./CompanyDotNetSdk.Tests/bin/Debug/net6.0/CompanyDotNetSdk.Tests.dll.config
./CompanytDotNetSdk.Tests/App.config

EDIT:
Following revomendation of @shingo I tried to run the test with strace and saw that the application tries to access file ./CompanyNETSDK/App.config and then ./CompanyDotNetSdk.Tests/App.config. So, I removed all other versions that tried to run the applicaiton with file located in these 2 places one-by-one with the same result.
What am I doing wrong? How to fix this problem?

The file name should be <appname>.exe.config. App.config is a file that should be put in the project.

@shingo, thank you for your reply. Yes, the app.config is a part of my project. It has been copied to bin folder by build (I think). Here is the full list of my config files:
./app.config
./CompanyNETSDK/app.config
./CompanyNETSDK/bin/Debug/net6.0/CompanytDotNetSdk.dll.config
./CompanyNETSDK/App.config
./App.config
./CompanyDotNetSdk.Tests/app.config
./CompanyDotNetSdk.Tests/bin/Debug/net6.0/CompanyDotNetSdk.dll.config
./CompanyDotNetSdk.Tests/bin/Debug/net6.0/CompanyDotNetSdk.Tests.dll.config
./CompanytDotNetSdk.Tests/App.config

@shingo, I have added the config files list to my question

Is the t between y and D just a typo? If the problem has not been resolved, I suggest using strace to see which file your program is trying to open.

Yes, it is dafinitely typo. Thank you. I have changed the name of the company I am working for to word "Company" just for this post.

@shingo, I tried to use strace. Although it was a good idea unfortunately It did not give me solution because I saw that the process tries to access "good" config files.

I am using Ubuntu 20.04, I installed .net 6.0 and tried to create a project from scratch with just this config file and the 2 lines of code, and it printed value=test. Have you tried with a single new project? BTW The way I use strace is to enter the bin/Debug/ne6.0/ folder and run strace -o strace.log ./CompanyNETSDK, in the log I can see something like openat(AT_FDCWD, "****/bin/Debug/net6.0/CompanyNETSDK.dll.config". Your full list is a bit strange. Normally, if the project is CompanyNETSDK, the generated config should also start with CompanyNETSDK.

I think the issue is with multiple app.config files, just create only one App.config and place it in the project directory.

I started from one. Due to it did not work I copied it everywhere

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
